# Why won't pandas read pickle file generated with older pandas version?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a very simple Series in pandas:

```
df8 = pd.Series([293.412, 290.743,283.179, 300.837, 334.139, 305.404], index = [0.00, 0.08, 0.16, 0.24, 0.32, 0.40])
```

[image]

I save this Series using:

```
df8.to_pickle('testdf')
```

When I reload the file using the same computer and hence the same pandas version (0.19.2) everything works fine with:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('testdf')
```

However, when I try the same on another computer with the pandas version (0.20.3) I get an error message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

Any idea how that problem could be solved?

Comment: Convert it to csv, the internal modules might have changed.

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to save and load between different pandas versions.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that part of the problem. So, what is the best way to transfer dataframes between different versions of pandas then?

Comment: I find statements like this: "pandas offers back compat not forward compat (meaning a newer versions can read older, but older cannot read newer)", that however doesn't seem to be true....